# SUPEE-8788 error in terminal when upgrading

Tags: magento

I am getting this error when trying to upgrade to latest patch SUPEE-8788 https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788 I am on Magento 1.9.2.2 and applied latest patches SUPEE-7405 v1.0 and SUPEE-7405 v1.1

This is the error:

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf.rej
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I met the same problem in SWF in 1.9.2.4.**

> **Fox Fixed - Please follow below steps.**
>
> **Step 1.** Download security patch 8788 SSH file to this Link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
>
> **Step 2.** After download security patch 8788 SSH file Please put into one folder and make same folder Zip file.
>
> **Step 3**. Please upload Zip folder to root Magento folder and Unzip through SSH Putty.
>
> **Step 4.** Run the patch :-
>   $ bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh

**Note: The patch file contains entire binary files in text format.That's why when you upload security patch 8788 SSH file without zip file, the same file will be corrupt. **

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issues in the same line. I don't know why but following suggestions I zipped the patch file, then uploaded it and unzipped it. Then using putty I was able to install it running sh PATCH....

Answer (score 1):

I simply removed lines 5951-9818 from the patch and manually removed the .swf files from `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media`, ran the script and then manually deleted the .swf files from the directory afterwards - since that's all the patch was doing anyway.

Comment: While it is a bit of manual effort, this is the same approach I took and it worked just fine.  Like you said, the patch is just trying to delete the file, so as long the file is gone all is good.

Answer (score 0):

The patch fails to detect the changes in `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf`, which is a binary file.

You should just pass the `-R` parameter on the command line, or type `y` when it asks whether to assume that.

Comment: Thing is that I can't enter `y` because it's skipping and continues. It's also strange because this binary file has never been touched.

Comment: Also with that `-R` parameter? However, if that all does not work, but the remaining files are patched successfully, you could copy the uploaderSingle.swf from a fresh downloaded v1.9.3 copy.

Comment: [This forum thread](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/patching-mit-quilt-was-mache-ich-falsch/) talks about a similar issue, and the reporter came to the conclusion he had a permission problem on the relevant directory. You could check the permissions on `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media` folder and/or on the `uploaderSingle.swf` file.

Comment: I've just tested this also and you're right. Zipping up the file first before uploading it (or uploading via binary) seems to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

zip the .sh file and upload it to the server. Unzip from there and then run it. It will work.

The problem is that when you upload the .sh file it messes up the .swf content (because it tries to upload it in ASCII).